# How to visit Stonehenge from Bristol or Bath?

Tags: public-transport, uk, bath-england, stonehenge, bristol

Next April we are going to spend 3 days in Bristol. We want to visit Bath and Stonehenge using public transport. I assume there will be a lot of trains/buses connecting Bristol and Bath, but I would like to know which is the best option to visit Stonehenge from one of these two cities.

Comment: Much of the related question [Visiting Stonehenge on the way from London to Bristol](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21456/visiting-stonehenge-on-the-way-from-london-to-bristol) will apply to this one too

Comment: I know it's not public transport, but I'll add a plug for [Mad Max Tours](http://www.madmaxtours.co.uk/index.php/tours/stonehenge-full-day-tour) for a tour of places that it's just a pain to get to by public transport from Bath.  We stayed in Bristol ourselves and used them for a great day out.

Comment: Wow! 32'50 pounds plus entrance fee!! Thanks, but too expensive for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bus is always cheaper but the train will be quicker.

It won't be hard to find either, personally I would take a specialist tour which would take you right up to Stonehenge itself, rather than having to go to Salisbury and then organise a taxi or local bus.

For trains from either Bristol or Bath check out:
http://www.firstgreatwestern.co.uk/

for National Express Coaches:
http://coach.nationalexpress.com/

But for specialist tours from Bath/Bristol
http://www.scarpertours.com/tour/stonehenge

Hope that helps

Edit:

You might want to check this too:
http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g186370-i379-k582873-Bath_to_Stonehenge_by_public_transit-Bath_Somerset_England.html